# Convert SSE intrinsics to readable C/C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, sse, readability

I've inherited some highly optimized (SSE4), but uncommented c code. Are there any tools or utilities that will convert the SSE intrinsics into more readable code or pseudocode? This would be primarily for readability so that I could understand the code better before digging in and making changes.

Comment: Look up what then mean in your compiler's manual and write yourself a cheat sheet of equivalent standard code?

Comment: No tools AFAIK, but SIMD code tends to use a small number of general "patterns" so the more you read and understand the code the easier it should get. Be prepared to draw lots of diagrams, particularly if there are neighbourhood operations (e.g. image processing, 2D filters, etc) - graph paper helps.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any such tool.

But it most likely would not help much anyway. If the SSE code is optimized well, the hard part is probably not decoding the intrinsics. The hard part is following all the tricks to improve locality and eliminate intra-iteration data dependencies (stripmining, polyhedral loop transformations, etc.)

I can give you a suggestion going forward, however: Always have a well-commented scalar version of the same routine written in the simplest possible way. This "reference code" should care only about readability and correctness, not speed... So it should have plenty of assertions. Also have a test suite that can exercise both the scalar version and the optimized variant(s).

Whether implementing a routine for the first time, or updating an existing routine, always start with the reference code and the test suite. Not necessarily in that order.

This approach is more expensive up front, but much much cheaper in the long run.

Comment: +1 for idea about the "reference code". Most of the time, I don't understand my own code when i read it later due to over-optimization. A readable reference code will solve that problem, I hope.